# Exception handling on external functions in a tkinter executable app

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

So i made a tkinter app and builded a executable, the development version works fine. But in the executable version only the Gui works, the aplication consist on 2 frames and in the last one i call a function from a external file that reads a csv. Some error is ocurring on my executable version and **i dont know how can debug to trace the error**. My main goal is to get a traceback, a error message box or even console warning, anything that could be able to inform the error on my external function when i run my executable.

Basic Structure of my file

Im using **cx_freeze** to build my exe

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from functionA import FunctionA

Main class

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
##External Function
from functionA import FunctionA

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

         # Frame inicial

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Carrefour NLC")
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, "500x400")
        tk.Tk.resizable(self, 0, 0)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        return frame
```

Frame where i call the external function who do the processing on my csv file.

```py
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        containerCode = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonCode = ttk.Button(
            containerCode, text="Realizar Codificação", command=lambda: openFolder())
        containerCode.pack(pady=20, padx=100)
        buttonCode.pack()

        def openFolder():
            savePath = filedialog.askdirectory()
            if savePath:
    ##External Function that i need to trace and handle exception and see if something goes wrong when i run my executable
                FunctionA(savePath)


        containerBottom = tk.Frame(self)
        button1 = ttk.Button(containerBottom, text="Voltar",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()
        containerBottom.pack(side="bottom", pady=20)
        button1.pack()
```

Comment: [You want the `logging` package](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html). A bit of pain to get started with, I have to say, but there are very good reasons for the apparent complexity, and it's really a package you __need__ to know how to use if you're doing any serious programming.

Comment: Thank you @bruno desthuilliers i will take a look